# jquery animate (height) causes background-image flickering in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-animate

I have a little Problem using jQuery.animate with firefox: when i animate the height of a container with some background image, the background starts to flicker on firefox only - all other browsers (even ie) show a smooth animation. a reduced code snippet that shows what i do:

```
<div style="background-image:url(image.jpg);background-position:50% 50%;height:200px;"
      onmouseover="jQuery(this).animate({height:400});"></div>
```

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: its currently on our local development server, but i will upload a demo later today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of interest, what happens if you wrap that in another DIV and animate that, e.g.

```
<div style="background-position:50% 50%;height:200px;" onmouseover="jQuery(this).animate({height:400});">
     <div style="background-image:url(image.jpg);"></div>
</div>
```

(For the record, I've used your code, but would have preferred using CSS Classes and Late jQuery event binding ;-)

Comment: i use late binding / css classes of course, but i wante to keep the example short ;)

Comment: oh, thanks for the hint - adding height:100% to the inner div works perfect